# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on using jQuery.lazy()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery's delayed image loading plugin to lazy load my images. While trying to do so I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the 2nd line of my code.

Here is my JS code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectTime: 1500
    });
});
```

This script is placed at the bottom of my page in a JS file along with some of my other scripts.

I have the following scripts in my `<head>` and I've verified that the files are indeed linked properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I have tried most of the solutions given to this problem on SO but I haven't had any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery lazy`](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) is a separate plugin, and is not available part of either `jquery`, or `jquery-ui`

You need to download and add a reference along with the rest of the jquery libraries

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I got confused because the documentation mentioned

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- or: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah.. that is a little misleading. Glad it helped.